# Inner Join запрос

Tags: mysql, ms-access, inner-join

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужна помощь в составлении Inner Join запроса двух таблиц Categories и Computers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто делаете обычный SELECT .. FROM .. (где указываете нужные колонки и основную таблицу) и приделываете к нему LEFT JOIN .. ON .. (где указываете дополнительную таблицу и правило для объединения):

```
SELECT Model, Categories.Name AS category
FROM Computers
INNER JOIN Categories
ON Computers.Id_category = Categories.Id
```

Проверка работоспособности: [db-fiddle.com/...](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qhEsQjuAA98hfaDQhmYoc7/0)

Comment: А почему именно LEFT ?

Comment: @Mike видимо привычка :) Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Запрос неверный. Попробуете выполнить - получите "unknown field".

Comment: @Akina Добавил `.Id` и реальную проверку кода.

Comment: Ну! это же ж совсем другое дело...